# MySQL Join help from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm sure there are a bunch of examples on S.O. but I don't even know what to search for since I'm very limited when it comes to working with databases, so I thought I'd post here and hope to get some help.

I have two tables, Users and Profiles.  There can be multiple profiles for one email, and there can multiple profiles for in the Users table.

I need to write a query that selects all of the profileIDs from the Profile table where the email matches ("test@test.com" for example.  This should return a bunch of profiles (1, 23, 444, 9203, 034)  But I only want to return the profileIDs (and username) that are in the Users table. (for example only profileID 444 is in the User's table.

Profile Table Example:

profileID | primaryEmail | name | otherStuff |

User Table:

profileID | username | password | otherUserStuff|

This is probably extremely simple, but it would take me quite a bit of time to research, and I'm on a time crunch.

Something like(?):

```
    SELECT t1.profileID, t2.username 
    FROM Profiles as t1 INNER JOIN Users as t2 ON t1.profileID = t2.profileID 
    WHERE t1.primaryEmail="test@test.com"
```

I'm a frontend dev that picked up a task that has a bunch more backend work than I thought.. and I'm already a couple days past the due date..

Comment: We aren't here to do your homework for you. Show us what you've tried, and the errors you're getting, and we can help you debug your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [sql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) from mysql's documentation site should help you form the query you're looking for, but for what a working join example would look something like this:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1 tableAlias
INNER JOIN table2 table2Alias ON tableAlias.column = table2Alias.column
WHERE tableAlias.column = this AND table2Alias.column = that
```

NOTE:  There's more than one type of join you can use, so take a moment to read through the documentation, and determine which one is best suited for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may write this query.

```
SELECT Profile.ProfileID, User.username from Profile INNER JOIN User ON Profile.ProfileID = User.ProfileID WHERE Profile.primaryEmail = "test@test.com"
```

Try it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProfileID, Username
  FROM Profile
  JOIN Users USING (ProfileID)
 WHERE primaryEmail = "test@test.com"
```

It will show data that exists in both table which has same `profileID`